# Nginx is not caching the path I setup to cache

Tags: nginx, caching

```
proxy_cache_path /tmp/nginx_team_alert_cache keys_zone=team_alerts:10m levels=1:2 max_size=1g use_temp_path=off;

server{
...
    location /api/timeentry/timeentry/team_alerts/ {
        proxy_cache team_alerts;
        proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control Set-Cookie;
        proxy_hide_header "Set-Cookie";
        proxy_cache_valid 200 5s;
        proxy_cache_key $scheme$host$request_method$request_uri;
        proxy_buffering on;
        add_header X-Cached $upstream_cache_status;

        include         uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass      unix:/tmp/app.sock;
    }
}
```

I have been searching on stackoverflow etc and added all the recommended options but still not caching.

Answer (score 0):

I just realised I am `uwsgi_pass` so the `proxy_*` directives won't work, simply replace `proxy_*` to `uwsgi_*` worked